# How long do metal, wood and other materials last when left unattended?

Tags: treasure, dungeon, dungeon-design

In most RPGs, adventurers break in long forgotten tombs filed with treasure that looks just like it was left there the day before. In a more realistic game, what would happen to materials left unattended for long periods of time?
How long would weaponry, jewelry, armor, coin, scrolls, books and other objects regularly found in treasure last in dungeonesque environs? What could make them last longer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think that experts in history (History.SE) would be better-equipped to answer it than experts in role-playing games.

Comment: Sorry guys! Didn't think the question wouldn't fit.

Comment: No apology necessary. It's kind of a weird edge-case where we're probably the ones who really *want* the answer, but they'll be better at answering it. If you get an answer over there I hope you'll drop a link here!

Comment: @nitsua60 I'm not sure History.SE is the place for this question either—they do history as in events and politics, not materials science related to age. Perhaps [physics.se] Se, or maybe even [DIY.se] SE.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie History.SE does have an [tag:archaelogy] tag which makes it onto their third of nineteen pages of tags; hopefully there are users over there that can help. It's been posted [here](http://history.stackexchange.com/q/28334/17229) and so far hasn't gotten what I'd call a warm welcome =( I'm sorry, MessyGoblin; if I'd anticipated that response I might never have voted to close here!

Comment: Hmm... so History.SE is saying it's off-topic there, because it's not "historical" enough. Which makes me feel even worse about the closure here. I suspect if I'd kept my mouth shut a good answer might have come along already.

Comment: It might fit more into world building SE

Comment: @nitsua60 Well, it's still solidly off-topic here; it falls into the non-RPG-info research category that we don't do.